# Django Default image for ImageField using Google Drive Storage

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield

I'm using an ImageField to store the images of my models and implementing Google Drive Storage as a backend to store the data. However, in some cases it is necessary to load a predetermined image.

So try to assign a static image from the model but it did not work

```
from django.db import models
from gdstorage.storage import GoogleDriveStorage 

# Define Google Drive Storage

gd_storage = GoogleDriveStorage ()

class Album (models.Model):

name = models.CharField (max_length = 250)
cover = models.ImageField (upload_to='images/', default='static/no_cover.jpg', storage=gd_storage)
```

Then I solve it from the template in the following way but I do not think it is the most ideal.

```
  {% if album.cover.url == None%}
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'no_cover.jpg'%}">
  {% else%}
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{album.cover.url}}">
  {% endif%}
```

Any idea how to load the static image?

Comment: The template solution is the best. You can't assign a default that easily and I wouldn't do it because it means copying the same image over and over again (and storing multiple copies of the same image).